# Find out exact time when the Ubuntu machine was rebooted

Tags: 16.04, reboot, uptime

`uptime -s` shows when the machine was started:

sample output: `2020-12-31 03:24:00`.

Is there a way to know the exact datetime when the machine was rebooted?

Answer (score 7):

```
last reboot | head -2
```

gives the last reboot times in a format like

```
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-58-generic Thu Dec 31 11:43   still running
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-58-generic Wed Dec 30 20:56 - 22:27  (01:30)
```

or use

```
last reboot --time-format full | head -2 | tail -1
```

to get something like

```
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-58-generic Wed Dec 30 20:56:16 2020 - Wed Dec 30 22:27:05 2020  (01:30)
```

or use something like awk to extract the end date

```
last reboot --time-format full | head -2 | tail -1 | awk -F ' - ' '{print $2}' | awk -F '(' '{print $1}'
```

-->

```
Wed Dec 30 22:27:05 2020
```

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-last-reboot-time-and-date-find-out.html

Comment: I would also add the [last manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/last.1.html) as a good reference for this command and other good uses it offers.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that the reboot was unclean and `last` returns several records which are `still running`